# Как вывести сохраненные значения в select2?

Tags: yii2, select2

Использую плагины от Kartik DepDrop и Select2
Во втором селекте я выбираю сразу несколько значений(multiple), у меня получается массив, через цикл я сохраняю данные в базу.
Вопрос, как при повторном открытие страницы с селектами загрузить сохраненные данные.  Вот мой код

```html
Использую плагины от Kartik DepDrop и Select2
Во втором селекте я выбираю сразу несколько значений(multiple), у меня получается массив 
Как мне сохранить это в базу, так чтобы при повторном открытие страницы с селектами у меня были уже выбранные ранее сохраненные значения.
Вот моя форма

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'games-form']);?>
            
  <?= $form->field($model, 'id')->label('')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(Platforms::find()->all(), 'id', 'name'), ['id'=>'cat-id', 'prompt' => '- ' . Yii::t('main', 'Select platform') . ' -']) ?>

  <?= $form->field($model, 'game_id')->label('')->widget(DepDrop::classname(), [
            'type' => DepDrop::TYPE_SELECT2,
            'options' => ['multiple' => true],
            'pluginOptions'=>[
                'depends'=>['cat-id'],
                'placeholder'=>'- ' . Yii::t('main', 'Select games') . ' -',
                'url'=>Url::to(['/user/default/getgame'])
            ]
        ]) 
    
    ?>
    
    <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('main', 'Save'), ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])?>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

соберите ваше значение в масивчик и запихните

```
'value' => ['red', 'green'], // initial value
```

ниже простой пример прямо из документации виджета

```
use kartik\widgets\Select2;
$data = [
    "red" => "red",
    "green" => "green",
    "blue" => "blue",
    "orange" => "orange",
    "white" => "white",
    "black" => "black",
    "purple" => "purple",
    "cyan" => "cyan",
    "teal" => "teal"
];

// Tagging support Multiple
echo '<label class="control-label">Tag Multiple</label>';
echo Select2::widget([
    'name' => 'color_1',
    'value' => ['red', 'green'], // initial value
    'data' => $data,
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select a color ...', 'multiple' => true],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'tags' => true,
        'maximumInputLength' => 10
    ],
]);
```

http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2#usage-tags

Comment: круто, еще бы с DepDrop соеденить

Comment: что именно нужно?

Comment: нужно выбрать в селект1  категорию, чтобы во второй загрузились записи выбранной категории, можно было выбрать не сколько записей и сохранить,   потом иметь возможность так же все это редактировать

Answer (score 0):

Делайте выборку из таблицы:

```
if (isset($model->field) ){
    $value= ArrayHelper::map(Table::find()->where(['id' => $model->field])->all(), 'id', 'field');
}else{
    $value= [];
}
```

И уже далее:

```
'data'=> $value,
```

Answer (score -1):

В базу сохраняйте в зависимости от вашей структуры.
Чтобы вывести при редактировании эти же данные используйте параметр data, и в него добавляйте данные по типу id => name:

```html
'data'=>[2 => 'Tablets'],
```

Подробнее: http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/depdrop#advanced-usage

Comment: Если добавить 'data'=>[2 => 'Tablets'], то это появится в выпадающем списке, а мне надо чтобы было уже выбрано.
1.  Сначала надо создать эти теги,
2 потом возможность их редактировать.

Comment: надо чтоб зайдя на страницу редактирования я получил это  http://a.disquscdn.com/uploads/mediaembed/images/4256/6595/original.jpg?w=800&h